# Linux shell to restrict sftp users to their home directories?

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

I need to give SFTP access to a directory within my webroot on my server. I've set up ben_files as a user and have set his home directory to

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.example/files
```

That's all fine if he connects with plain old FTP - he's restricted just to that directory, but to enable SFTP I had to add him to bin/bash shell, which suddenly opens up my entire server...

Is there a way of giving him SFTP access but without opening up all my directories? I'd really like him restricted to only his home.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

OpenSSH≥4.8 supports a `ChrootDirectory` directive.

Add to `/etc/sshd_config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or whatever your setup's global `sshd` config file is:

```
Match user ben_files
        # The following two directives force ben_files to become chrooted
        # and only have sftp available.  No other chroot setup is required.
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.example/files
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        # For additional paranoia, disallow all types of port forwardings.
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: Hiya, I get some errors - Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 113: Bad configuration option: Match AND /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 115: Bad configuration option: ForceCommand. These both stop sshd coming back up again. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably don't have a new enough SSH version.

Comment: ahh yeah, i missed that bit in your answer - we're on 4.3, i'll look at getting that upgraded.

Comment: Oh wow, 4.3 is 4 years old by now; you're still using it?  Upgrade!  5.3 is the current latest release.

Comment: That's plesk for you... They package up all sorts of old versions with custom tweaks. Hate it tbh.

Comment: @matt ryan: The goal here is to deny the user all access other than sftp.

Comment: @ephemient yes, they were denied using sftp. but, i realized my issue was ownership over the home directory. i set it root:root 755 and it's all good

Answer (score 3):

You might try setting his shell to `/bin/rbash`

> RESTRICTED SHELL
>          If bash is started with the name rbash, or the -r option is
>   supplied at
>          invocation, the shell becomes restricted.  A restricted shell  is 
>   used
>          to  set  up an environment more controlled than the standard shell. 
>   It
>          behaves identically to bash with the exception that the  following
>   are
>          disallowed or not performed:
>
> ```
>    ·      changing directories with cd
> ```

plus more...

Make sure you fully understand what is allowed and disallowed before you use this.

Comment: rbash is in the distro, but it doesnt appear to allow sftp - i'll have to look into the configuration i guess. Thanks for the tip tho!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [rssh](http://pizzashack.org/rssh/).  It may already be packaged for your o/s distribution.

Comment: It's not packaged, but that is perfect! I'll look at getting that installed asap ;) Thanks!

Comment: rssh is now unmaintained, and lacks security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pam_chroot`.

Here is a good manual: [Chrooted SSH/SFTP Tutorial (Debian Etch)](https://www.howtoforge.com/chroot_ssh_sftp_debian_etch)

Answer (score -2):

You can also set the users shell to /bin/false by using:

```
usermod -s /bin/false username
```

Restricts them from ssh'ing in and can only sftp (or ftp, if it's setup)

I use this for sftp usres, along with the mentioned chroot setup (covered by other answers).

Comment: When I set my shell to /bin/false, I can no longer sftp or scp to it!

Comment: `/bin/false` restricts any kind of login attempt. Your information is false. Use `/sbin/nologin`  instead