# Create a SFTP user to access only one directory.

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sftp, sshd

I need to create a user which can only SFTP to specific directory and take a copy of some infomation. that is it. I keep looking online and they bring up information about chroot and modifying the the sshd_config.

So far I can just

- add the user "useradd sftpexport"
- create it without a home directory "-M"
- set its login location "-d /u02/export/cdrs" (Where the information is stored)
- not allow it to use ssh "-s /bin/false"

> useradd sftpexport -M -d /u02/export/cdrs -s /bin/false

Can anyone suggest what am meant to edit so the user can only login and copy the file off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux shell to restrict sftp users to their home directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526919/linux-shell-to-restrict-sftp-users-to-their-home-directories)

Comment: Did you find what was the issue with your `useradd` command? (without having to create a new user group)

Answer (score 38):

I prefer to create a user group `sftp` and restrict users in that group to their home directory.

First, edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and add this at the bottom.

```
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

This tells OpenSSH that all users in the sftp group are to be chrooted to their home directory (which `%h` represents in the ChrootDirectory command)

Add a new sftp group, add your user to the group, restrict him from ssh access and define his home directory.

```
groupadd sftp
usermod username -g sftp
usermod username -s /bin/false
usermod username -d /home/username
```

Restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

If you are still experiencing problems, check that the directory permissions are correct on the home directory.  Adjust the 755 value appropriately for your setup.

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/username
```

EDIT:  Based on the details of your question, it looks like you are just missing the sshd_config portion.  In your case, substitute `sftp` with `sftpexport`.  Also be sure that the file permissions are accessible on the `/u02/export/cdrs` directory.

An even better setup (and there are even better setups than what I am about to propose) is to symlink the `/u02/export/cdrs` directory to the user home directory.

Comment: question does the directory have to be owned by him? as it own by another user. I have added him to the same group as said user as well.

Comment: Please read up on user privileges.  The 3 numbers correspond to user, group and others (world).  It is imperative that you learn what these mean and how to use them safely.  Do a google search but here is one post http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-file-and-directory-permissions/

Comment: One side-note of the `bin/false`. For readers, you might check whether you actually need it before copy-and-pasting. For example there is an related answer https://serverfault.com/a/519218/394787

Comment: Don't forget to change default Subsystem in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from `#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` to `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

Answer (score 3):

You could need to add a restricted shell for this user can put some files there. You can use [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) tool for that.

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/rssh sftpexport
```

Enable allowed protocols in config `/etc/rssh.conf`.

Comment: rssh is now unmaintained.